# Force word-break with hyphens with CSS if and only if there isn't enough room for the whole word on the next line

Tags: css

Not sure if I'm wording this right.

Right now I'm using the following CSS to hyphenate long words on my web page, which works pretty well:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

What I would like, however, is to have a fallback that attempts to push the whole word (and subsequent words) to the next line if the next word can fit the line, as opposed to breaking/hyphenating any word near the edge of my container, regardless of length.

Basically, here's what's going on:

-----------------------
The quick br-
own fox jumps ov-
er the lazy dog
Somereallyrdic-
oulosly long word
-----------------------

What I would like is:

-----------------------
The quick
brown fox jumps
over the lazy
dog
Somereallyrdic-
oulosly long word
-----------------------

Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: Do you have any other CSS being applied, or what browser are you using? If I try your code in Chrome I get the example you would like (i.e. only the very long word breaks), but no hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with html `&shy;`. Unfortunately it does not read minds - hard code is necessary.
In any place in which you let a word break put `&shy;` with no spaces - it is invisible in html. If the word doesn't fit - it will break with a nice `hyphen` at this point.
(I don't know where from are `-` in your example - my browser just breaks)

`word-wrap`, `word-break` and `hyphens` are useful for long links (and aren't full supported). You can use a combination if needed

```css
p{ width: 100px; border: 1px solid red; margin: 0 50px; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. Somereally&shy;ridicoulosly long word</p>

<p><b>This_one_is_without_shy</b> Auxerunt&shy;haec&shy;vulgi&shy;sordidioris&shy;audaciam, quod&shy;cum&shy;ingravesceret&shy;penuria </span>
```